# CometD / jQuery Client Error 402::Unknown Client

Tags: java, comet, cometd

I'm trying to get started with CometD as I need some empirical background for a technical comparision between various push technologies.

I finally managed to get an example code running in my Tomcat (v7.0).

Now I'm having strange behavior and I'm desperately trying to find out what I did wrong.

**Here are my observations:**

- Connection Loops:

  I'm running in an endless connection loop with the client.

  Request:

  ```
  [{"channel":"/meta/connect","connectionType":"long-polling","id":"19","clientId":"f1le33y91f6pa71f39z52km87yp"}]
  ```

  Response:

  ```
  [{"id":"19","successful":true,"advice":{"interval":2000,"reconnect":"retry","multiple-clients":true,"timeout":60000},"channel":"/meta/connect"}]
  ```

  The interesting thing about this is, that the Listener-callback event actually occures

  ```
   cometd.addListener('/meta/handshake', _metaHandshake);
  ```
- Client connection request stucks

  This mostly occurs after a fresh restart of my Tomcat server. I can see a successful subscription to 2 channels:

  Request

  ```
  [{"version":"1.0","minimumVersion":"0.9","channel":"/meta/handshake","supportedConnectionTypes":["long-polling","callback-polling"],"advice":{"timeout":60000,"interval":0},"id":"1"}]
  ```

  Response

  ```
  [{"id":"1","minimumVersion":"1.0","supportedConnectionTypes":["callback-polling","long-polling"],"successful":true,"channel":"/meta/handshake","clientId":"11tnpjnmkqo3tf64zcvufuqbtv","version":"1.0"}]
  ```

  Request

  ```
  [{"channel":"/meta/subscribe","subscription":"/hello","id":"2","clientId":"11tnpjnmkqo3tf64zcvufuqbtv"},{"channel":"/service/hello","data":{"name":"World"},"id":"3","clientId":"11tnpjnmkqo3tf64zcvufuqbtv"}]
  ```

  Response

  ```
  [{"id":"2","subscription":"/hello","successful":true,"channel":"/meta/subscribe"},{"id":"3","successful":true,"channel":"/service/hello"}]
  ```

  The call after this one stucks and takes forever.

**... abd here is my Code**

- Client

  ```
  (function($)
   {
     var cometd = $.cometd;

  $(document).ready(function()
  {
      function _connectionEstablished()
      {
          $('#body').append('<div>CometD Connection Established</div>');
      }

      function _connectionBroken()
      {
          $('#body').append('<div>CometD Connection Broken</div>');
      }

      function _connectionClosed()
      {
          $('#body').append('<div>CometD Connection Closed</div>');
      }

      // Function that manages the connection status with the Bayeux server
      var _connected = false;
      function _metaConnect(message)
      {
          if (cometd.isDisconnected())
          {
              _connected = false;
              _connectionClosed();
              return;
          }

          var wasConnected = _connected;
          _connected = message.successful === true;
          if (!wasConnected && _connected)
          {
              _connectionEstablished();
          }
          else if (wasConnected && !_connected)
          {
              _connectionBroken();
          }
      }

      // Function invoked when first contacting the server and
      // when the server has lost the state of this client
      function _metaHandshake(handshake)
      {
          if (handshake.successful === true)
          {
             // interesting enough: that event is triggered
              alert('event occured');
              cometd.batch(function()
              {
                  // that function is called and produces a corresponding request to the server
                  cometd.subscribe('/hello', function(message)
                  {
                      // that one never happens... 
                      $('#body').append('<div>Server Says: ' + message.data.greeting + '</div>');
                  });
                  // Publish on a service channel since the message is for the server only
                  cometd.publish('/service/hello', { name: 'World' });
              });
          }
      }

      // Disconnect when the page unloads
      $(window).unload(function()
      {
          cometd.disconnect(true);
      });

      var cometURL = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + config.contextPath + "/cometd";
      cometd.configure({
          url: cometURL,
          logLevel: 'debug'
      });

      cometd.addListener('/meta/handshake', _metaHandshake);
      cometd.addListener('/meta/connect', _metaConnect);

      cometd.handshake();
  });
  })(jQuery);
  ```
- Server

  Notice that this is almost 1:1 from the example from the distribution package!

  ```
  public class HelloService extends AbstractService
  {
  public HelloService(BayeuxServer bayeux)
  {
      super(bayeux, "hello");
      addService("/service/hello", "processHello");
  }

  public void processHello(ServerSession remote, Message message)
  {
      Map<String, Object> input = message.getDataAsMap();
      String name = (String)input.get("name");

      Map<String, Object> output = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      output.put("greeting", "Hello, " + name);
      remote.deliver(getServerSession(), "/hello", output, null);
  }
  ```

  }
- Web.xml File

  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
           version="2.5">

  ```
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>cometd</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.cometd.server.CometdServlet</servlet-class>
      <async-supported>true</async-supported>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>timeout</param-name>
          <param-value>60000</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
          <param-value>3</param-value>
      </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>cometd</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/cometd/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  ```

Maybe I'm just doing something completely wrong, but I'm starting to get a bit desperate on this. Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry if the title is misleading, actually I figured out that the exception 402 is raised when I accidentally restarted tomcat while I wrote this post.

Comment: For that particular line of code where you comment "that one never happens", have you tried doing a publish to that channel? That function is only called when a message comes in through the "/hello" channel.